How to query MongoDB Atlas from a shell script?
I've been trying to write a shell script to restore a MongoDB Atlas instance using a snapshot, and then query said instance to validate the results. While I can use API calls to get the snapshotIDs and perform the backups/restores without any problem, actually querying said instance from the script has been giving me issues. There doesn't seem to be an explicit API call to run queries, at least not that I've found. I have tried using MongoSH commands to query, like the following:
collection_list=mongosh --quiet "mongodb+srv://'${dev_creds}'@sandbox.vk4dz.mongodb.net/" --apiVersion 1 --eval "db.getCollectionNames()"
However, when I run this, I receive an "Authentication failed" error, regardless of how I format my credentials. I know the credentials work, as I'm able to sign in with them, and was able to initiate a restore API call with them earlier. Have I just missed something in this command?
I've tried to format the command differently, and checked to ensure that the connection string I'm generating looks legitimate. I've also tried to use a API get request to query the data as well, but so far have not been able sign in. I've also tried various queries to ensure that the query in question was not the cause of the issue, and I've attempted to run the command without the variable name at the beginning as well.

It must be like this:
dev_creds='domscheit:secretPassword'
mongosh --quiet "mongodb+srv://${dev_creds}@sandbox.vk4dz.mongodb.net/" --eval "db.getCollectionNames()"

--apiVersion is not needed.
Ensure database user is created and has sufficient privileges, see Configure Database Users
You could also use this:
mongosh --quiet "mongodb+srv://sandbox.vk4dz.mongodb.net/" --eval "db.getSiblingDB('admin').auth('domscheit', 'secretPassword'); db.getCollectionNames()"

Note, with your connection string, you use default database 'test'. You can specify database with db.getSiblingDB('...') or you can include it in the connection string. However, then you need to specify also the authentication database:
mongosh --quiet "mongodb+srv://${dev_creds}@sandbox.vk4dz.mongodb.net/myDb?authSource=admin"


Thank you very much! Using an admin user was the correct way to go. API keys weren't working for it.

In this case, please accept the answer
